# Dismiss modal UIView after authenticating with Facebook

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

My app brings up a modal UIView with a button to allow a user to authenticate with Facebook. After the user switches to the Facebook app, gets authenticated, then is sent back to my app, I want this modal view to get dismissed automatically.

How can I tell the user authenticated successfully and then dismiss the controller?

I'm guessing I should do something with the notification center, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this after using the Notification Center in this method in the app delegate. When we get a valid session, it sends a notification to the modal view telling it to dismiss.

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            if (!error) {
                // We have a valid session
                NSLog(@"User session found");
                NSDictionary *extraInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"FBLoginStatus" forKey:@"FBLogin"];
                NSNotification *note = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"FBLoginNote" object:self userInfo:extraInfo];
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:note];
            }
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better to use delegate methods rather than notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean you're presenting a modal `UIViewController` it can be dismissed with the following.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

[UIViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Oh, I know how to dismiss the window. I'm asking how to make the app understand that it's now authenticated with Facebook so it can dismiss the window.

Comment: @bmueller It's hard for me to say without you posting the code you're using, but I'd imagine you'll want to look for the completion handler in your code for receiving login authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the last Facebook SDK, all you need to do is implement the dismissal once the action has finished successfully. This is done by placing the code in the "`-(void)fbDidLogin` delegate method.

Comment: Hmm, I am using the latest SDK, and I tried `- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSLog(@"FB LOGGED IN");
}` but nothing showed up in my log.

Comment: Hooking everything up when using the Facebook iOS SDK can sometimes be tricky. Make sure you've followed all the steps, including the required appDelegate methods and URL scheme configuration in the info.plist of your project.

Answer (score 0):

In you `appDelegate` do this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [[yourViewController facebook] handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

Comment: How does that make a modal view get dismissed?

Comment: I posted this answer because you mentioned that nothing showed up when you did an NSLog in `- (void)fbDidLogin`